# Repeatedly try perform MySQL query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen somewhere something like the code below. It is intended to make multiple attempts to perform a query if it has failed with anything else than deadlock error. I just want to ask you guys if is it a good practice or does it have any benefits?

```
    $success = false;
    $try_count = 5;
    do{
        try {
            $this->_db->beginTransaction();

            // PERFORM QUERY 1

            // PERFORM QUERY 2

            $this->_db->commit();
            $success = true;
            return true;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->_db->rollBack();
            $try_count--;
            $success = false;
            // if not deadlock error, throw it
            if($e->getCode()!=1213) throw $e;
            if($try_count < 1) return false;
        }
    }while($try_count > 1 && !$success);
```

Comment: Can you name a reason, why this should be useful?

Comment: It is not at all a good practice.

Comment: @Dainis Abols Not really. That's why I asked you the experienced programmers if is it a good practice or does it have any benefits?

Comment: No, it's not a good practice at all. If a query fails, it should be investigated, not re-forced like that.

Comment: You might want to post this question on codereview.stackoverflow.com ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a bad practice unless you have a very good reason. I say this because you would have to add logic to see what caused the error and respond differently to each error before deciding to re-query the database. Cheers :)